# "Type Mismatch" for the inputbox set on type=2 from a string input

Tags: excel, vba

I get the following error message

[image]

after giving the input "Table5"

The error occurs for the code:

```
TableName = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Enter the target table name", _
    Title:="Table Name", _
    Type:=1 + 2, _
    Default:="Table1")
On Error GoTo 0
```

I tried setting the type on

- "2"
- "1 + 2"

The macro is supposed to fill a column with a function such as  `"=COUNTIF(TableName[ColumnName], FALSE)"`

- The column to fill (TargetRange) is the first variable.
- The ColumnName is the second variable. It's a column with the name of the column of the table. The range is the same as TargetRange
- TableName is the name of the table with the column name and the false result to count

expected result :
[image]

First time that I write a macro in VBA

````
Dim TableName, TargetRange As Range, ColumnName As Range

'Input variables'
Set TargetRange = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select the output range where result will be pasted", _
    Title:="Output Range", _
    Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If TargetRange Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ColumnName = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select range containing the column name", _
    Title:="Column name", _
    Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If ColumnName Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

TableName = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Enter the name of the table", _
    Title:="Table Name", _
    Type:=1 + 2, _
    Default:="Table1")
On Error GoTo 0

'For Loop'
Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim Name

For Each TargetCell In TargetRange
    For Each Name In ColumnName
        Range(TargetCell).Value = "=COUNTIF(" & TableName & "[" & ColumnName & "], FALSE)"
        On Error Resume Next
        Next Name
    Next TargetCell

End Sub```
````

Comment: `Set` is for object variables.

Comment: `TargetCell` is an range not an address so `Range(TargetCell)` is not valid. 
If `ColumnName` is more than 1 cell then `"[" & ColumnName & "]` is a type mismatch. If `ColumnName` is one cell then remove the `For Each Name loop` and try `TargetCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & TableName & "[" & ColumnName & "], FALSE)"`

Comment: @BigBen `TargetRange` and confusingly `ColumnName` are both range objects.

Comment: @CDP1802 but `TableName` isn't (or shouldn't be). OP [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77135046/3) out the `Set` previously there.

Comment: @bigben Ah, that explains why `If TableName Is Nothing` makes no sense :.)

Comment: I updated the code. I tried to add the feedback based on what I understand. my goal is just to select the cell (eg. 7 cells) where to insert formulas, then select the same number of cells to retrieve the column name, then enter the table name, to get the number of false for each column (1506 columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the table name from the selected column names without having to enter it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountFalse()

    Dim rngTarget As Range, rngColumnNames As Range
    Dim name As Range, Tablename As String, n As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select the output range where result will be pasted", _
        Title:="Output Range", _
        Type:=8)
    
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set rngColumnNames = Application.InputBox( _
        prompt:="Select range with the column name", _
        Title:="Column name", _
        Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngColumnNames Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Tablename = rngColumnNames.ListObject.name
    For Each name In rngColumnNames
        With rngTarget.Cells(n)
            ' column name to left
            .Offset(, -1) = name.Value2
            .Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & Tablename & "[" & name & "], FALSE)"
        End With
        n = n + 1
    Next name
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thx. I had to change a little bit the way I selected the range, but it works and fix my problem. I will analyze your code later to see what I can learn from it